# android canvas scroll in the simplest form

Tags: android, canvas, scroll

i am new to android and cannot find any suitable way to make a canvas scrollable. I have searched a lot but no one's giving a complete overview of what is to be done actually. Just vague ideas & incomplete code examples. Any help would be appreciated. I have extended the from scrollview and have drawn a png image on canvas which is greater than the screen size. Scrollbar do show up but then fade away & no scrolling. what am i missing?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you have a custom view with a Canvas you're drawing to, then you have to implement scrolling yourself. But fear not! There is a nice things called [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) and [Scroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) already made for you to make it easy.

You just need to listen to its scrolling/fling events and update xOffset value with which you gonna draw on your Canvas.

Basically in your draw(Canvas) method you don't just call

```
drawSomething(x, y)
```

but

```
drawSomething(x - offset, y)
```

If I'm describing the problem you have and it's still unclear - let me know, I can expand further.

Comment: You can check out my github custom view demonstration. Particularly - this class https://github.com/TheHiddenDuck/custom_view_keyboard/blob/master/src/com/evilduck/piano/views/instrument/PianoView.java

Comment: please forgive my ignorance... I have problems run the project... how can I run it on my phone? download everything and then?

Comment: you download sources from github, then open it in eclipse (create new android project from existing code) or any other IDE and just run the project